# Why good mid-IR materials with wide band gap can have good performance?

Tags: condensed-matter

To make SHG process happen, materials need to absorb light. However, for mid-IR materials with wide band gap, they are transparent to mid-IR light. How can SHG process happen in these materials? Many articles (on acs publication) choose wide band gap materials is because they have larger laser damage threshold. Isn't materials with narrow band gap can absorb mid-IR light? I'm really confused.

Comment: Second harmonic generation does not occur through absorption. It is a non-linear response of the material.

Comment: Isn't during the SHG process, two photons with same frequency are absorbed and one photon with doubled frequency is emitted?

Comment: No, photons of one color mix to form the other. You can down mix, or do sum/difference frequency mixing as well. The medium itself is non-linear. No absorption wanted.

Comment: Yes, the medium itself is nonlinear and photons of one color can mix to form different colors. But the first paragraph in Wikipidia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation) says that two photons interact with a nonlinear material (only interact, no absorption?). And the first figure show the virtural state. So there is actually no absorption but we could imagine the absorption process happens so a photon with doubled frequency is produced? I'm very confused.

Comment: I’d more say interact through (because of) the non linearity of the medium. And definitely no absorption into an excited state.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer. I'm convinced that there is no absorption.